# Why do the grid children change size depending on the content

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Here is the desired result with plain grid

[image]

original code:

```
import { Card } from "@/components/ui/card";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto max-w-screen-xl xl:h-[50rem] px-4 xl:px-0 xl:grid xl:grid-flow-col xl:grid-rows-4 xl:gap-6">
      <div className="h-[20rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-2">
        <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[20rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-2">
        <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[40rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-4">
        <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[10rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-1">
        <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[30rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-3">
        <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However when i add content inside of it, the shape i made changes.

But if i add width it dose not

```
import { Card } from "@/components/ui/card";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto max-w-screen-xl xl:h-[50rem] px-4 xl:px-0 xl:grid xl:grid-flow-col xl:grid-rows-4 xl:gap-6">
      <div className="h-[20rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-2 xl:w-[27rem]">
        <Card className="w-full h-full overflow-auto">lorem1000</Card>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[20rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-2 xl:w-[27rem]">
        <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[40rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-4 xl:w-[27rem]">
        <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[10rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-1 xl:w-[27rem]">
        <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[30rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-3 xl:w-[27rem]">
        <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

is there a way to achieve this without me defining the width specifically, i.e `w-[27rem]` or is this how css works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the grid container to have a number of columns to ensure that they stay formatted like you have in the photo above, and then you can dictate the number of columns that the grid elements take up. Its pretty much the same idea as what you've done with the `row-span`:

```html
<div className="mx-auto max-w-screen-xl xl:h-[50rem] px-4 xl:px-0 xl:grid xl:grid-flow-col xl:grid-rows-4 xl:gap-6 xl:grid-cols-3">
  <div className="h-[20rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-2 xl:col-span-1">
    <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
  </div>
  <div className="h-[20rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-2 xl:col-span-1">
    <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
  </div>
  <div className="h-[40rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-4 xl:col-span-1">
    <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
  </div>
  <div className="h-[10rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-1 xl:col-span-1">
    <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
  </div>
  <div className="h-[30rem] xl:h-auto xl:row-span-3 xl:col-span-1">
    <Card className="w-full h-full">hello</Card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach works as well, the content stays within and dose not change the layout of the elements around it.